# If statements on Access 2013 forms

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Okay, so I'm creating a new database, and I've written several queries that I now wish to link a form.  A partial view of the form will be attached [image: Partial Form]

What I want this form to do is when the user selects the manufacturer the model box will be a drop down with only models linked to that manufacturer

IE: If the user selects Dell they will get a list of only Dell products that I've added to the model table in the database.  If they select apple, they'll only get apple models, and so on.

I have the queries written to separate the data already, I'm just lost at the syntax needed on the source control for the forms.

I've looked around Stack Overflow and found nothing, and I checked the msdn to see if I could find any clues, so far I've not been able to figure this out, so now I'm asking for help.

Comment: What you need is called [Cascading ComboBoxes](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/forms/combo-boxes/cascading.html)

Comment: Okay, thank you for your comment. I looked up some videos on Cascading comboboxes, it does look like what I'm looking for.  Sorry it's taken so long to get back to you, I've had to make some adjustments to my database design so that I could achieve the comboboxes correctly.

Comment: If you'll put this in the form of an answer I'll go ahead and approve it. I did get the results I wanted out of doing this.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you, I have done it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup you need is what is called as [Cascading ComboBoxes](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/forms/combo-boxes/cascading.html) - Filtering the records in one combo box based on the value selected in another.

With this, you will be editing the rowsource of the next combobox that follow, so it will be more like a filtered list, that gives you more flexibility to choose and filter. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
select Modelname
from  Models
where Models.Manufacturer = [Forms]![ManufacturerField].value
```